# How to get places between give two city using Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project, My task is to get the total no of places between given two city.
For example, I enter "city1" and "city2" and i want to get all the corporate office of Oracle Company with their complete address.

When i am using google map api, it shows only for a particular city not between two cities.

anyone have any idea about this. Please help me.

Comment: by the way have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/about . You have other questions with answers but did not mark them as correct or interacted with them further. People try to help you! Give them feedback!

Answer (score 0):

First of all there needs to be a definition of what "between" actually means. Probably a corridor with a certain width starting from A and ending at B will be the result of that.
Once this definition has been established you can use a database that supports GEO querys to get all your places entries contained within this region.

The google maps API would only be used to display Data to the user and aid in the selection of the cities.

There is a library that aids in detecting weather a point is inside a polygon (your corrdior)
https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon
That would be another ways to get the points between your cities on the client.